# Terraform / config: unknown variable referenced

Tags: terraform

I have .tf file in pt-plan directory with the following express:

```
${lookup(var.prod, var.pt)}
```

In addition I have the following `terraform.tfvars` file:

```
variable "prod" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    pt = "https://pt:9200"
  }
}
```

When I run:

`/terraform plan pt-plan`, it writes:

```
unknown variable referenced: 'prod'. define it with 'variable' blocks
unknown variable referenced: 'pt'. define it with 'variable' blocks
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: That's not how you define vars in terraform.tfvars files. That needs to be in a .tf file in your directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax:

`"${var.prod["pt"]}"`

Or this:

`"${lookup(var.prod, "pt")}"`

instead of:

`"${lookup(var.prod, var.pt)}"`

the [`var.`] before 'pt' above is redundant, also 'pt' must be quoted.

Comment: This won't work because the lookup map needs to be in a .tf file not a .tfvars file.

Comment: Yes, that too: .tfvars files are just to provide the actual values for existing variables, not declaration of a var. Declaration must be in a .tf file. But the syntax still must be followed as provided above.